# What's the best way to redeploy asp.net core web api on IIS without stopping the application?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

For now I've to (re)deploy asp.net core web api on Windows server with IIS. I know how to deploy and its working currently in production. The issue is every time I make a change I have to stop the website/recycle the apppool to be able to copy the application dlls. This is a pain as I'm looking to ultimately setup CI/CD using some provider however without this knowledge I'm unable to move forward.